# how to edit the .profile file to have shortcuts for commands?

Tags: bash, node.js, environment-variables

im really new to unix, i wanted to learn how to edit a .profile script on OSX lion to help me have shortcut for this directory:

```
/usr/local/cellar/node_modules/node.io/bin/node.io
```

i want to be able to run the program like this:

```
node.io -h
```

instead of :

```
/usr/local/cellar/node_modules/node.io/bin/node.io -h
```

for some reason npm hasn't decided to set paths for me, even though i used -g, so going to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

`export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/cellar/node_modules/node.io/bin`